# Import data from a CSV file into SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, csv

I'm trying for several hours to write a simple application in C# that retrieves data from a CSV file to the SQLite database. The problem is that I do not know how to transfer the data to the database. I was looking for tutorials on the internet but none of them helped. Could someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Your issue is putting data from csv to sqlitedb, not displaying on gird, right?

Comment: Please post your attempt and any questions where you may be stuck.  I suggest trying to use Entity Framework to work with SQLite.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Reading the csv file? Writing to the sqlite database? The are many many, really good tutorials on working with sqlite from .net.

Comment: I need to download the data to the SQLite database and then display those data (from the database) in Grid.

Comment: Your UI layer and how you intend to display the data is irrelevant, your problem is reading a CSV file and writing the data into the SQLite database file so I removed the WPF tag and part of the question pertaining to that to allow everyone to focus on the core problem and  once you solve the core issue you can post another question on how to populate a WPF grid with that data you stored in the SQLite database which is very simple and will boil down to creating a POCO class to correspond to your data, populating a collection with that data and binding the collection to DataGrid...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you'll keep working your data, there's no need to fill an sqlite just to show csv to datagrid...
What about to test [CsvHelper](http://csvhelper.com)?

Comment: I know that I can display data from file in the grid but I've to use any database.

Comment: I highly suggest that you focus at one problem each time...
- Read csv;
- Shows to datagrid;
- Append to database;
At any order...

Comment: The problem is that I must first send data to database from a CSV file. This is a current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "[A Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)" over at CP. It will allow you to read a CSV file into any type of in-memory structure you like (DataTable, collection of objects) and free [Telerik Data Access](http://www.telerik.com/data-access) ORM which supports SQLite will allow you to write that data to SQLite database file.